# Why Retrofit @Path is not replacing?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a big project that's using Retrofit 2.0 beta2, however it seems like @Path is broken somehow.

This is the log from server side when receiving the request: /group/%7Bid%7D/users
The "{}" is identified as encoded value rather replacing it with the actual value.

I tried to create a test project and it seems working, but when I tried the same code in the big project, it breaks! What could be the reason? Is proguarding an issue here?

this is the simple interface I tested

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
Call<Object> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://1.1.1.1:5050")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
RetrofitConfigurationService2 service = retrofit.create(RetrofitConfigurationService2.class);
    service.groupList(12).enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Object> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to -keep interface com.yourretrofitinterface.** { *; }
in the proguard file.

Comment: This solves the problem, otherwise the @Path tag is not kept in the apk when you use Proguard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same the problem.
A more generic solution would be adding the following to your proguard rules.

```
 -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
     @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
 }
```

Complete rules regarding retro:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontnote okhttp3.**, retrofit2.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
     @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now try to read this blog: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

> Retrofit 2.0 comes with new URL resolving concept. Base URL and @Url
> have not just simply been combined together but have been resolved the
> same way as what  does instead.

The author concludes:

> - Base URL: always ends with /
> - @Url: DO NOT start with /

If you are using Proguard in your project add the following lines to your configuration:

> -dontwarn retrofit.**
>
> -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
>
> -keepattributes Signature
>
> -keepattributes Exceptions

Comment: Did you even read the description? I created a test project and it works fine. Same code does't work in another big project.

Comment: you add strings: -dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions into your proguard-rules?

Comment: I was suspecting the issue might be with proguard, will try and let you know

Comment: yes, it might be proguard, because retrofit working using reflection. I will be happy to help

Comment: Hi, unfortunately disable proguard and multidex doesn't seem to work!!! This issue is killing me now :(